# Getting null value for embedded object in a room entity

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am using room for my database in an android application, and while listing the objects from the database, an embedded field in the object is not being parsed and results in null.

Here is the definition of the embedded object.

```
public class Price {
    @NonNull
    private Double price;

    @NonNull
    private Date date;

    public Price(Double price, Date date) {
        Log.e("TEST3", "Asset price " + price + " " + date.toString());
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Then I am using an abstract class where the above object is embedded.

```
public abstract class PriceHistory {
    @NonNull
    @Embedded
    private Price price;

    @NonNull
    @TypeConverters(TimestampConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated_timestamp")
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp;

    @Ignore
    public PriceHistory(@NonNull Price price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.lastUpdatedTimestamp = DateTimeUtil.getCurrentTimestamp();
    }

    public PriceHistory(@NonNull Price price, @NonNull Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp) {
        this.price = price;
        this.lastUpdatedTimestamp = lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Price getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(@NonNull Price price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Timestamp getLastUpdatedTimestamp() {
        return lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedTimestamp(@NonNull Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp) {
        this.lastUpdatedTimestamp = lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    }
}
```

And, then I am extending the above class for the actual entity used for the database as follows

```
@Entity(tableName = "specific_price_history", primaryKeys = {"code", "date"})
public class SpecificPriceHistory extends PriceHistory {
    @NonNull
    private String code;

    @Ignore
    public SpecificPriceHistory(@NonNull String code, @NonNull Price price) {
        super(price);
        this.code = code;
    }

    public SpecificPriceHistory(@NonNull Price price, @NonNull Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp, @NonNull String code) {
        super(price, lastUpdatedTimestamp);
        if(price == null) {
            Log.e("TEST2", "Still getting null");
        }

        this.code = code;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(@NonNull String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

The list query for querying the database in the dao is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM specific_price_history WHERE code = :code ORDER BY date ASC")
    public abstract List<SpecificPriceHistory> listHistory(String code);
```

When I use the above list query, here are my observations:

- The number of items fetched is consistent, but calling the getter for the price object returns null.
- The constructor of the Price class does get the correct price and date.
- But, the constructor of the final entity class gets a null argument for the price object.

I used adb to read the actual database for my application, and the database has the correct values. Also, if I change the query to just read Date from the database, the query works fine and returns the date.

I know I am missing something very stupid here, but I have been scratching my head all day now! :(